# What does an orange square by folder in Package Explorer mean?

Tags: java, eclipse, icons, package-explorer

I'm completely new to Java and Eclipse. I developed my first "Hello, world" program the other day following along with a tutorial. I understand most of the Eclipse UI since I worked with Flash Builder for awhile which was built on top of the Eclipse IDE.

My question is, what does an orange square by folder in Package Explorer mean exactly? I imported the project "Hello, world" into the workspace on OSX and that's the first time I ever seen this orange square. I am really curious about it as it isn't on any of the rest of my projects?

I referred to; http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

For a reference of icons in the Kepler IDE (btw that's what I'm using) and I found an orange square amongst the icons labeled "a monitor that is owned by a thread"; I don't understand the termonology used though... I don't even know if that is the correct icon I'm looking for?

Here it is;
[image: A moniter that's owned by a thread???]

And here's a screenshot of my package explorer...
[image: What does that orange square mean???]

See them orange-looking squares? They look very similar but I'm not 100% sure. I really appreciate your help on this.

Thank you!

Comment: I couldn't find this? I tried searching and searching but it is impossible to search something like this unless you know the terminology of what the icon is...

Comment: I did a Google search for _eclipse icon adornment_ and it was the first result. (Granted, you need to know the magic words to feed to Google. However, the Eclipse doc page that you linked to in your question uses that terminology, so it shouldn't be considered an impossible search.)

Comment: But there isn't any icon on that page that tells you... Hey, this orange hard-disk symbol is an 'eclispe icon adornment'. All I could find was that similar icon under debug which I mention aboved. So for a first timer like me, I didn't have a clue what 'eclipse icon adornments' were, and this could potentially help others as well who don't understand these icons.

Comment: @W3Geek It's fine, you are not expected to know every question in [so] before you ask your question.  Having a duplicate question does not affect your reputation score in any way (the question upvotes still add to it though).  In fact, having this new question here might help someone who searched for "orange square."  So it's all good here.

Comment: I've been using Eclipse for a decade and have never heard the term "adornment"; I'd have looked for "label" or "badge".

Comment: @chrylis - If you never heard the term "adornment" then you never read the [Eclipse docs](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm) on those icons.

Comment: @TedHopp I hadn't. It appears the Eclipse documentation is improved over the last time I tried to wade through it, when I just gave up and started going through the source code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not quite an orange square; it's an orange hard-disk symbol. It indicates that the file or directory labeled is under version control. (A plus in that position indicates that a file has been added to the git index but not yet committed, and a question mark indicates a file that is not under version control when its containing project is.)

Comment: 1+ Ahhh! =D That is why I wasn't seeing this in the tutorials! I'm using GIT for version control to back up code and use it as a future reference (if needed). I tried searching this but it was impossible to find it... Thank you so much for clarifying on this!